# How can I solve IndexError: list index out of range in a list of dict?

Tags: python, api, index-error

for the following code I am getting

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 24, in
>
> artist_uri = json_data['artists']['items'][0]['id'] IndexError: list index out of range.

Anyone can tell me how to solve this?

```
for item in (fd):
  
  artist = item['Name']
  headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer xxxxx',
    }

  params = (
    ('q', artist),
    ('type', 'artist'),
    )
  response = requests.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/search', headers=headers, params=params)
  
  json_data = json.loads(response.text) # convert json response to text/dict
  artist_uri = json_data['artists']['items'][0]['id']
  print(artist_uri)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the artist: "ANAVITÃÂRIA" cannot be retrieved from the Spotify API. The following is the response your script get when you try it:

```
{
  "artists" : {
    "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=ANAVIT%C3%83%C2%83%C3%82%C2%93RIA&type=artist&offset=0&limit=20",
    "items" : [ ],
    "limit" : 20,
    "next" : null,
    "offset" : 0,
    "previous" : null,
    "total" : 0
  }
```

Sometimes it is might be due to the characters in the name. To avoid this error, rate-limiting issue and continue the loop you can check whether there are data in the current API response and also the status code of the API Response Check the updated code: (Please update the bearer token when you try it)

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json
import time

fd = pd.read_csv('fd.csv',sep=';',encoding='latin1') # Reading data from csv
fd = fd.T.to_dict().values() # Converting dataframe into list of dictionaries

for item in (fd):
  
  artist = item['Name']
  headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer xxxxxx',
    }

  params = (
    ('q', artist),
    ('type', 'artist'),
    )
  

  response = requests.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/search', headers=headers, params=params)
  if response.status_code != 429:
    json_data = json.loads(response.text) # convert json response to text/dict
    
    if (len(json_data['artists']['items']) > 0):
      artist_uri = json_data['artists']['items'][0]['id']
      print(artist_uri)
  else:
    time.sleep(30)
    response = requests.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/search', headers=headers, params=params)
    json_data = json.loads(response.text) # convert json response to text/dict
    
    if (len(json_data['artists']['items']) > 0):
      artist_uri = json_data['artists']['items'][0]['id']
      print(artist_uri)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. However, I am a beginner and this version is really complicated to me. encoding='latin1' is not supposed to solve problem with non latin characters?

Comment: I only modified a few lines of your code to make it work. I don't think encoding in "latin-1" will solve the problem because the artist's name passes in a different way to the API. Please upvote or approve this answer if it helped :)